# Remove td's outside borders

Tags: html, css, html-table

I currently have this table:

[image: Table]

with this following markup:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="3">
    <thead>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"></td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm currently having trouble removing the outside border of the bottom left `td` element. There is a border beneath where I have drawn the red lines but I do not want them there.

Is there an easy way to go about removing this?

EDIT:

Expected result:

[image: Expected Table]

Comment: create and share a fiddle of the same!

Comment: @Sunny Just get the markup I posted and post it in the html section of jsfiddle. I blocked out all the data in the fields as it was sensitive information.

Comment: Remove border from table element and instead add to specific td as required

Comment: there are two broders(cell + total table) all over.which one you want to remove.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai I want to remove the outside borders of both as I specified.

Comment: I recommend doing the border in css. And then use something like "tr:last-child td:first-child" to select that td. But in answer to your question, no there is no easy way that I am aware of.

Answer (score 2):

Its a bit tricky to achieve what you expect, I have a kind of work around

But if you want the exact output you might need to get rid of table and use div, span etc with some css

Please check this fiddle to see if it helps
[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sunnypmody/v7NzD/)

```
<table>
<thead>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="border: 0;"></td>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

```
td {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: 2px solid gray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give that specific `td` an ID in the tag and then use CSS to remove the border:

```
border-left: none;
border-bottom: none;
```

Comment: You've misunderstood. I've edited my question to add the expected result.

Comment: You will have to get specific with your borders in css for this problem. You can specify each side of the border using border-right, border-left etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is little tricky. You can't achieve this straightway. But you can achieve this  using some additional code. The idea is to create one div on that particular table column assign left and right border as a white color text. Assign margin to minus value so that it will hide the original table border.

**HTML:**

```
 <table cellpadding="3" border="1">
<thead>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>44</td>
        <td>55</td>
        <td>66</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="border:0px; border-top:1px solid #000; border-right:1px solid #000;"><div style="margin-left:-6px; border:1px solid #fff; margin-bottom:-6px; height:100%;">
            <div style="padding:5px">te</div>

        </div></td>
        <td colspan="2">as</td>
        <td>bs</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/YsrCF/)

Comment: Mine is not a proper solution. But it will give the idea to go inside.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you are still interested. Here is an idea using `:after`.

[Have a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/YsrCF/4/)

CSS

```
table {
    border: solid 1px #000;
}
td {
    border: solid 1px #000;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100px;
}
.borderless {
    border: none;
    position: relative;
}
.borderless:after {
    content:"";
    border-top: solid 1px #000;
    border-right: solid 1px #000;
    display: block;
    height: 62px;
    width: 287px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -3px;
    background: #FFF;
}
```

HTML

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" class="borderless">Content</td>
            <td colspan="2">Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: So this looks bang on the money :)

Comment: Might just be my browser but your css for `:after` is off. http://jsfiddle.net/YsrCF/5/ fixes it.

Comment: interesting, your example is off for me :) Chrome - latest stable version. Height is off by two pixels.

Comment: How about this? [This is using padding and no height](http://jsfiddle.net/YsrCF/6/). Works nicely for me.

Comment: I don't know if you can achieve this consistently across browsers. It is a hack after all... For instance [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YsrCF/8/) works nicely in Firefox latest stable but the border is too thin in Chrome. I would just go for a single border if I was you. This seems like too much overhead.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="3">
    <thead>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"></td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>




td {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
td[colspan="3"] { 
    border:none;
    position:relative;
}
td[colspan="3"]:after {
     content:"";
    border-top: solid 1px #000;
    border-right: solid 1px #000;
    display: block;
    height: 24px;
    width: 132px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -3px;
    background: #FFF;
}
```

[Demo success](http://jsfiddle.net/rvpatel/ZG7Yr/2/)

[image]